# Stage execution only if last commit contain keyword

Tags: azure-devops

In yml file I have a stage(named RELEASE) that need to be executed only if the trigging commit contain cetain keyword, my pipeline is trigged by commit.

the predefined variable *Build.SourceVersionMessage* is only available at task level, I use it today to skip individually every task of the RELEASE stage, but I'm searching to skip all the stage at once.

Any idea how to do this properly without using bash export or database insert ?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are workarounds to achieve this.
1,
The first workaround needs you to add a script task to output a variable with the value of `Build.SourceVersionMessage` in the previous stage. And add a `dependency` and `condition` in Release stage. You can refer to below example:

```
stages: 
  - stage: Publish
    displayName: 'Publish stage'
    jobs:
    - job: jobA
      pool: Default
  ...
    - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=commitMessage;isOutput=true]$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)"
      name: setvarStep
       
  - stage: Release
      dependsOn: Publish
      condition: contains(dependencies.<Previous stage name>.outputs['<name of the job which execute the task.setvariable >.setvarStep.commitMessage'], 'keyword')
      jobs:
      - job:
        ....
```

2.
The other workaround to achieve this is to add an another stage with a powershell task which evaluates the value of `Build.SourceVersionMessage`. Then add a dependency and condition in Release stage on this stage.

In below example,stage **GetSourceMessage** have a job with a single powershell task which will fail if `Build.SourceVersionMessage` does not contain 'keyword'. And stage **Release** depends on stage **GetSourceMessage** will only be executed on condition of stage **GetSourceMessage** succeeded.

```
...
- stage: GetSourceMessage
    jobs:
    - job: jobofstage2
      steps: 
        - powershell: |     
            if('$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)' -inotmatch  "key")
            {
                exit 1
            }

  - stage: Release
    dependsOn: GetSourceMessage
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
...
```

Comment: the first solution is working on my test pipeline. Could you post your yaml code? and the error message if there is any?

Comment: `- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=commitMessage;isOutput=true]$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)"
      name: setvarStep
- stage: Release
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: contains(dependencies.Publish.outputs['Build.setvarStep.commitMessage'], '==RELEASE==')
  jobs:..............`

Comment: no error message but the stage is always skipped even if the commit contain ==RELEASE== keyword

Comment: There is a mistake in your yaml code. The first stage name is "Build". So the condition should be `contains(dependencies.Build.outputs['Build.setvarStep.commitMessage']`. I update my solution, so it would be clearer